Children that never saw the sun
This is a movie from 80s I think. 
There was some kind of disaster and the atmosphere was covered with some kind of dust and all plants died. 
So there's a classroom of children that never saw the sun. It the end the clouds clear up and starts raining. So they have the experience to see sun and plants for the first time.

After re-watching this movie after 30 years when I was a kid it's funny to see how the memory retained some parts and changed others.

I think it might be All Summer in a Day, a TV short from 1982 based on a Ray Bradbury story.

On the planet Venus, it rains almost constantly. A classroom full of
  young children are excited to hear that the rain will stop today, for
  just one hour. But they are also resentful of a new classmate from
  Earth, who remembers what it's like to see the sun.


Yes, I think it's this one. My memories about the movie are very slim. Thanks
